# PHP: problems with reading the content type of a file

Tags: php, content-type, mime

I have a question regarding to mime types and how to handle them in php.

My problem:

I have a class "CSSFile" that repreents a valid css file. When instanzing it with the path to the file, my class is supposed to check if the css file is valid. This is done by checking the mime type. The mime type is determined to be "text/css" if the file is a normal css file. Great!

But I want to allow the class to accept php-files that are sending css-header:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

when validating this file, php determines the mime type "text/x-php". 
Damn, I thought by setting a header like this I could make my file to be a valid css file for php. (Am I doing something wrong here?)

Ok, my solution now is to read the header of my php-css-file to get the content type "text/css". I just can't figure out how to get the header in aclean way without including the file. I wrote this method:

```
private function getContentType(){

    \ob_start();
    include $this->relativePath;
    \ob_end_clean();

    $headerList = \headers_list();

    $fileHeader = \array_pop($headerList);
    $parsedHeader = \explode(':', $fileHeader);

        if(!empty($parsedHeader)){

            $key = \array_search('Content-type', $parsedHeader);

                if($key !== FALSE && \array_key_exists(($key + 1), $parsedHeader)){

                    $contentType = \explode(';', $parsedHeader[($key + 1)]);

                        if(!empty($contentType)){ return  \trim(\array_shift($contentType)); }
                }
        } 

    return NULL;
}
```

This method indeed returns the content type "text/css". But I somehow don't like this solution. I don't like to include a file to check its content type by reading the recieved header. Looks for me like really bad style. Maybe I could load the content of the file via "file_get_contents" but parsing the content type then seems to be a pain. Is there a better way to solve this problem propely.

So if you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _“when validating this file, php determines the mime type "text/x-php". Damn, I thought by setting a header like this I could make my file to be a valid css file for php”_ – first of all, you have to make yourself aware of the fundamental difference between a _file_ and an _HTTP resource_.

Comment: Your HTTP resource (with the Content-Type header) is generated by running PHP code. The only way of obtaining that Content-Type header is by running it (or, as you are doing, parsing the code).

Comment: But I'd rather argue that your design is smelly.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What are you doing with this CSS? Getting by POST? Or sending to browser? Or what? What is the problem?

Comment: You want to validate php file as proper css file in local filesystem?? You crazy???

Comment: Yes it actually is smelly. It is for an template engine (just for learning purpose for myself). the idea was to set css files for certain templates. My template engine has an class CSSFile that represent an css file and tries to sort out invalid (in some way) css files (for preventing myself of making mistakes). The class is then also in charge of creating the proper link-tags to include the file. So its really more about the question how to determine the content type than how senseful it is

Comment: `header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");` is enough for browser to know what it is.

Comment: Allright, so there is actually no other way...
Well, at least I learned something about mime and stuff :)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in php, which provides mime type for the specified file:

**http://php.net/mime_content_type**

Also, since it has been deprecated, there is PECL extension to replace it (as stated on php.net):

**http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php**

Do you think you can make use of those?

Comment: I use this functions. That is not a problem. The problem is, that my css-file is actualy a php file sending a css-header (because I want to use variables in my css file to be able to make quick changes).
the mentioned functions get me the mime type "text/x-php" instead of the content type given in the files header "text/css"

Comment: So? I don't understand the problem then.

Comment: Then your question is not really the detection of mime type for a file. Also, if you need variables in CSS you should look into SASS.

Comment: @FlashThunder: the problem is that I set the content-type of the file to "text/css". When reading the mime type I get "text/x-php". Thats ok, because its an php file. But I want to get the "text/css" set in the header of the file. D. Kasipovic just made it clear: its my mistake, it looks like I'm actually not needing the mime type. I'll see..

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to kiss my idea of having php-css files goodbye. Damn, looks like there is no way around SASS or LESS or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If it is send by POST method, simply use `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']`.